# The mbstring extension not seen by phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, server, mbstring

I know there has been a lot of questions about this, but they didn't helped me to solve my problem.

I get this error when trying to access phpMyAdmin:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error

The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

I am running php7.0 - in `php.ini` located in `etc/php/7.0/apache2` I have this:

```
extension_dir = "./"
extension_dir = "mods-available"
```

uncomented. I've also tried

```
extension_dir = "./"
extension_dir = "ext"
```

but it didn't work and I don't have any `"ext"` directory in `etc/php/7.0/` so it doesnt make any sense to have it there right? Anyway I tried both options and I tried restarting apache after setting either one of them, but nothing works.

Furthermore when running

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

I get output:

```
php7.0-mbstring is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
php7.0-mbstring set to manually installed.
```

which means it's already installed right? If I `ls` the directory `etc/php/7.0/mods-available` I can see file called `mbstring.ini` which I suppose is the proof it's installed. But when trying to access phpMyAdmin it still says that mbstring is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since installing the extension?

Comment: `php -m` lists your PHP modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is all over the place so let me start from scratch:

1. Run `phpinfo();` from a test file and check out the `extension_dir`
2. Does the `extension_dir` point to the right place? Yes, great! No, fix it.
3. Does the extension exist in `extension_dir`? Yes, nice. No, add the extension.

---

Also, why do you have:

```
extension_dir = "./"
extension_dir = "mods-available"
```

Did you need this instead?

```
extension_dir = "./mods-available"
```

---

It might be worth trying a full path like I use on my Windows machine:

```
extension_dir = "C:\\PHP\\x86\\7.0.2\\ext"
```

Comment: Yep, the true path was actually "/usr/lib/php/20151012" as shown in phpinfo like you said. It works now, thanks!